# Are the iterates of the cosine linearly independent?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Consider the cosine function $f = \cos : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$.

Is it true that the set of iterates
$$\left\{f_n := \cos \circ \dotsb \circ \cos,  \; n \text{  times }   \mid  n \geq 1\right\}$$
is linearly independent over $\Bbb R$ ?
That is, I am wondering if,  for any $r \geq 1$ and any real numbers $a_k$, we have :
$$\sum_{k=1}^r a_k f_k = 0 : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R \implies a_k=0 \;\forall k.$$

I know that this true if we consider the *powers* of $\cos( \cdot )$, but I don't know how to deal with compositions.
What I tried is to take derivative, or induction on the minimal length of linear dependence relation.

Comment: You could use Taylor expansion, but I'm not certain that there will be a nice pattern allowing for an easy proof with arbitrary $n$.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you can use the fact that $\cos(x)$ and its iterates are entire functions of a complex variable, you can use the following idea (I use your notations): We proceed by inductioon, the case $n=1$ is obvious.

Let $n\geq 2$, and suppose that $a_1f_1(x)+a_2f_2(x)+\cdots+a_nf_n(x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Then this imply that $g(z)=a_1z+a_2f_1(z)+\cdots+a_nf_{n-1}(z)$ is zero for all $z\in [-1,1]$ (because $g(\cos(x))=0$, we have put $z=\cos(x)$). As $g$ is entire, this imply that $g(z)=0$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$, and that $a_1z$ is periodic with period $2\pi$. Hence $a_1=0$. Now , putting $b_1=a_2,...$ etc, we have $b_1f_1(x)+\cdots+b_{n-1}f_{n-1}(x)=0$ for all $x$. The  induction hypothesis apply, and we are done. .

Comment: OK. I see it now. It is not very obvious that in the second line you used the change of variable $z=\cos(x)$, you should probably indicate that.

Comment: This appears to be a rare case when all previous downvoters checked on the edited post and either removed or reversed their downvotes. Nice answer.