# Linear independence of iterates of a unbounded discontinuous function

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Consider the function $f : x \mapsto \lfloor x \cos(x) \rfloor$ on the real numbers.

I would like to know whether the functions 
$f_n := \underbrace{f \circ ... \circ f}_{n \text{ times }}$ (with $n \geq 1$) are linearly independent over $\Bbb R$ (in the real vector space $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$).

---

The answers to my [previous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2703313/linear-independence-of-iterates-of-a-non-continuous-function) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2702135/are-the-iterates-of-the-cosine-linearly-independent) cannot be applied, since $f$ is cannot be extended to a holomorphic function, and $f$ is not bounded.
I don't even know how to show that $f=f_1$ and $f_2$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb R$.
Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: You have come up with a recipe for an interesting series of questions.  That being said, is there any particular inspiration for this line of questioning?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : I was first interested about iterates of cosines, but the (nice) answer involved complex analysis. Here there is probably no way to use to power of complex analysis, that's why I'm interested in knowing how one could prove linear (in)dependence.

Comment: I understand that, but what made you think about the iterates of $\cos$ in the first place?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : I first saw a question on powers of $\cos$ being linearly independent. I noticed that I had almost no idea how to prove linear independence of the _iterates_ of $\cos$, that's why I asked.

Comment: I see.  Well, definitely an interesting idea.

Comment: For what it's worth: my idea at first glance is that perhaps we can find a lower bound for the first $n$ such that $x \mapsto x \cos(x)$ is linearly dependent to smaller powers over the restricted domain $[-T,T]$.